# Is this a correct method to store state for a std::allocator - in this case, backed by shared memory on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shared-memory, allocator

The [implementation](https://github.com/venkatperi/shm-allocator) of a std::allocator (based on [MAllocator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/08/28/the-mallocator.aspx)) backed by Windows named shared memory, adds a couple of items to MAllocator.

- An additional parameter **name** for allocate(), alters the signature over std::allocator. Is this **ok**, considering that allocators are typically template parameters (errors will be caught at compile time)?

  `template<class T> T *allocate(const size_t n, const char* name);`
- State is maintained in the form of a map of pointers to handles for deallocate(). The allocator denys equality with other instances to preserve state integrity. Is this sufficient or are additional safeguards needed?

  ```
  typedef std::map<uintptr_t, HANDLE> HandleMap;
  HandleMap mHandles;

  deallocate(T *const p, size_t n = 0) 
  {
      if (mHandles.find((uintptr_t)p) == mHandles.end())  //we don't own this pointer
      {
          std::ostringstream msg;
          msg << "Error in deallocate(): Invalid pointer - we don't own it - we can't delete it!";
          throw std::exception(msg.str().c_str() );
      }

      unmapView(p);
      closeHandle(p);
      mHandles.erase((uintptr_t)p);
  }
  ```

Full code on [github](https://github.com/venkatperi/shm-allocator)

Comment: I'm not an expert at all, but pre-2011 C++ derivatives of std::allocator could not have state, whereas post 2011 they are allowed to have state. However, this implies that valid pre-2011 code using allocators may not be valid post 2011 code. In order to be valid post-2011, your containers (or any other code using the allocator) must use the very same allocator instance for allocation and deallocation.

Comment: btw, do you really think *anybody* would wade through your endless code? make a small example containing all the essence.

Comment: the 2nd arg to `deallocate` isn't used.

Comment: The 2nd arg, `size_t n`, is a hint to deallocate() and indicates how many objects of sizeof(T) are being deallocated, in case the underlying scheme can benefit from it. ShmAllocator deallocates all of the memory pointed to by the first arg.

Comment: in case of the above example, however, the 2nd argument is not used and hence should not be named, i.e. `deallocate(T*const p, size_t=0)`, to avoid compiler warnings about unused variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your question says "for a std::allocator" but this is not a `std::allocator`, it's a `ShmAllocator`. `std::allocator` is a class template provided by the standard library, your allocator is not that class template, it's a different type.  I think you mean "for an allocator" or just "for a standard allocator", which refers to a type conforming to the allocator requirements (`std::allocator` is just one example of such a type.)

This fails to meet the allocator requirements, specifically a copy is not equal to the original object. If you plan to use this allocator with code that expects a standard-conforming allocator it could fail.  If you don't plan to use it with code that expects a standard allocator, then why bother copying its interface?

The requirements for the copy constructor require that for an object `a` of type `ShmAllocator<T>` the statement `ShmAllocator<T> a1(a);` is valid, with the post-condition that `a1 == a`, and for an object `b` of type `ShmAllocator<U>` the statement `ShmAllocator<T> a(b);` is valid, with the post-condition that `ShmAllocator<U>(a) == b` and `a == ShmAllocator<T>(b)`.

These requirements are necessary because containers need to be able to rebind allocators and make copies which must be able to free each others memory.  Equality for stateful allocators should be dependent on value not identity.

To make your allocator meet the requirements you could store `mHandles` as `shared_ptr<mHandles>` so that copies of the allocator can all share the same collection.

How do you plan to use this allocator? I don't know the Windows API functions, but it appears that every time you call `allocate` you need to use a different value for `name` or you will get the same pointer returned, which means it can't be used by standard containers.  I would expect a shared-memory allocator to create a shared-memory region in its constructor (or be constructed with a reference to some existing region, e.g. see Boost.Interprocess allocators) then divide that region up and return different chunks of it every time `allocate` is called, rather than create a new region on every call to `allocate`.  Is this intended to be user to share objects between processes? How will another process get access to an existing object? It seems the other process would have to call `allocate` to get a pointer to an already constructed object. That's confusing, `allocate` should give new, uninitialized memory.  A shared-memory allocator would usually define a custom pointer type which stores an offset into the shared-memory region not an absolute address, so that when such a pointer is used in a different process the offset is still valid, even if the region is mapped to a different address.